# RDP on premises with 2FA on Azure AD

Tags: remote-desktop-services, entra-id, two-factor-authentication

We are looking to implement a two-factor authentication mechanism for our client's Remote Desktop servers (not running on Azure). All my clients have Azure Active Directory, so I thought I could integrate those two systems (RDP and Azure AD) so that connecting via RDP would require 2FA.

Have any one tried this before?

Cheers

S.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, we cannot achieve this through Azure.

However, if you still want to achieve that, you need to setup  **RD Gateway and NPS server**. See more details about how to secure the RDP connection Using Azure MFA for windows, please refer to [this Blog](http://azuredummies.com/2017/07/01/securing-rdp-connection-using-azure-mfa-for-windows-2012-r22016/) .

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi,@gsandorx , If this answer is helpful to you, please mark it as answer , so that we can help more communities! Thanks!

Comment: Is this still true?  (It's now 2020)